# Multiple instances of HTTPD running, and virtual memory constantly running out?

Tags: vps, virtual-machines, httpd, memory-usage

I've noticed my VPS behaving weird today. I have set it up as a web server (along with MySQL, PHP, FTP etc) and at the moment there is only one website running on there. I noticed earlier today that the website would loose connection to the database intermittently, and would also fail to load at all.

I opened Webmin and when it eventually loaded (it took a while) it reported back that the CPU usuage for I/O was 100%, and that 125.39MB of the 125.47MB Virtual RAM was used up. I reset the VPS and after it came back online, the CPU read that it was running at 100% Idle and that 0KB of RAM was being used.

After 1 hour 44 minutes, the server now says that I'm using 7.36MB of RAM. It also says that I have 66 processes running, and on looking at that I have 9 instances of httpd service running.

I'm thinking that the httpd services are eating up the RAM and CPU (each instance is reporting that it's using roughly 330000KB of RAM). As I only have one website running on the server (and one instance of Webmin) shouldn't I expect to see only one instance of httpd running? Or is this normal?

If the multiple instances of httpd aren't the problem, what else could be causing these issues?

**EDIT:**
The processes listed by CPU usage are:

```
ID      Owner       CPU     Command   
2401    root    1.3 %   /usr/libexec/webmin/proc/index_cpu.cgi<br />
1   root    0.0 %   /sbin/init<br />
2   root    0.0 %   [kthreadd]<br />
3   root    0.0 %   [migration/0]<br />
4   root    0.0 %   [ksoftirqd/0]<br />
5   root    0.0 %   [watchdog/0]<br />
6   root    0.0 %   [events/0]<br />
7   root    0.0 %   [cpuset]<br />
8   root    0.0 %   [khelper]<br />
9   root    0.0 %   [netns]<br />
10  root    0.0 %   [async/mgr]<br />

The processes by RAM are:
1034    mysql   444648 kB   /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-e ...<br />
1156    apache  334512 kB   /usr/sbin/httpd<br />
1157    apache  333728 kB   /usr/sbin/httpd<br />
1161    apache  333728 kB   /usr/sbin/httpd<br />
1136    root    319352 kB   /usr/sbin/httpd<br />
1158    apache  319352 kB   /usr/sbin/httpd<br />
1159    apache  319352 kB   /usr/sbin/httpd<br />
1160    apache  319352 kB   /usr/sbin/httpd<br />
1162    apache  319352 kB   /usr/sbin/httpd<br />
1163    apache  319352 kB   /usr/sbin/httpd<br />
882 root    248576 kB   /sbin/rsyslogd -c 4<br />
1144    root    117072 kB   crond<br />
1960    root    108212 kB   -bash<br />
945 root    108076 kB   /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/my ...<br />
1957    root    97456 kB    sshd: root@pts/0<br />
2486    root    67068 kB    /usr/libexec/webmin/proc/index_size.cgi<br />
1164    root    64152 kB    /usr/bin/perl /usr/libexec/webmin/miniserv.pl /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf<br />
2489    root    64152 kB    /usr/bin/perl /usr/libexec/webmin/miniserv.pl /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf<br />
909 root    63756 kB    /usr/sbin/sshd<br />
1135    postfix 62220 kB    qmgr -l -t fifo -u<br />
2062    postfix 62048 kB    pickup -l -t fifo -u<br />
1126    root    61968 kB    /usr/libexec/postfix/master<br />
1   root    19112 kB    /sbin/init<br />
2498    root    11208 kB    sh -c ps --cols 2048 -eo user:80,ruser:80,group:80,rgroup:80,pid,ppid,pgid,pcpu, ...<br />
2499    root    11092 kB    ps --cols 2048 -eo user:80,ruser:80,group:80,rgroup:80,pid,ppid,pgid,pcpu,vsz,ni ...<br />
358 root    10860 kB    /sbin/udevd -d<br />
615 root    10856 kB    /sbin/udevd -d<br />
894 root    3988 kB /usr/sbin/acpid<br />
1172    root    3984 kB /sbin/agetty /dev/ttyS0 9600 vt100-nav<br />
```

Comment: Can you run `top`, sort by CPU% and see what the busiest processes are?

Comment: The busiest process is `/usr/libexec/webmin/proc/index_cpu.cgi` at 4.0%. But thats it, none of the other processes have any CPU usage?

Comment: Hmm, what does the "Cpu(s)" line say from top?  On my non-busy system, I see: "Cpu(s):  0.7%us,  0.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st".  Also, what's the output from `free -m`?

Comment: Added the output in the question.

Comment: Can you actually get a shell and run commands? Or are you limited to your control panel?

Comment: I have terminal access, and I can get the top command to work. But I can't order it by CPU, although I can tell you that there are no processes using any of the CPU.

Comment: It might be worthwhile contacting support at your VPS provider.  I've seen cases where my VPS is dog slow with high CPU I/O usage being caused by a different VPS on the same hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked down the problem to Webmin running. I've left the Webmin service off all night and the RAM usage is under control now. I have now since deleted Webmin and using ISP Config 3 instead. Again, the RAM usage is incredibly good now.